# Core Data Widget with shared container conflict

Tags: core-data, swiftui, widget, ios14

## The Scenario

I'm using `Core Data` inside my main app and my widget.
To share my `Persistent Container` I use this custom stack that targets both my app and my widget and its working fine

```swift
class CoreDataService {
    
    static let shared = CoreDataService()
    
    lazy var context: NSManagedObjectContext = persistentContainer.viewContext
    
    lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentCloudKitContainer = {
        
        let container = NSPersistentCloudKitContainer(name: "my.app.name")
        let storeURL = URL.storeURL(for: "my.app.group", databaseName: "my.app.name")
        let storeDescription = NSPersistentStoreDescription(url: storeURL)
        container.persistentStoreDescriptions = [storeDescription]
        container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
            if let error = error as NSError? {
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            }
        })
        
        return container
    }()

    func saveContext () {
        let context = self.context
        if context.hasChanges {
            do {
                try context.save()
            } catch {
                let nserror = error as NSError
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

## The Problem

But when I access my widget from the home and I tap it to go to the app, whenever I use @FetchRequest in my code I get this error

```
CoreData: error: +[Subject entity] Failed to find a unique match for an NSEntityDescription to a managed object subclass
```

And then my app crashes with this `Stack Trace`

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'executeFetchRequest:error: A fetch request must have an entity.'
```

## Workaround

I partially solved it by changing this FetchRequest

```swift
@FetchRequest(entity: Subject.entity(), sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Subject.name, ascending: true)]) private var subjects: FetchedResults<Subject>
```

to this one

```swift
@FetchRequest(fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Subject")) private var subjects: FetchedResults<Subject>
```

But still don't know what I did wrong in the first place and why is this stupid change solving my problem and I would like to know if there is another way to solve it.

Comment: What if you try `let _ = CoreDataService.shared.context` at the very beginning when your app starts? (Just to be check if the `context` is properly loaded before you execute the `@FetchRequest`.)

Comment: I think I can say that im already sure that the context is properly loaded because both my app and my widget work fine. this only appens when my widget is on the home screen, if i remove it there are no crashes.